# Indexing error with an array in a dictionary (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am having an issue displaying indexed objects in a table view. I have indexed the objects as a list of clients based on the first letter of their name. The indexed results are put into a dictionary like this

```
{Char: [Client]}
```

Char being the first character of the client's name and [Client] being an array of client objects, who have the first letter of their name matching the Char. When printed out, this shows up like this:

```
{'D': [Client("David"), Client("Dan")]}
```

However, when I go to set these titles in the tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) function, I get an index out of bounds error. The client array has a count of 3 and the contacts dictionary has a count of two, but has all 3 objects it as such:

```
{'S': [Client("Sam")], 'D': [Client("David"), Client("Dan")]}
```

How do I go through the dictionary properly to get individual clients into each table cell with the proper section headers? I am using Swift 3.0. Below I have posted how I indexed it as well as the function I am trying to override.

**ClientTableViewController.swift**

```
var clients = Client.loadAllClients()

var contacts = [Character: [Client]]()

var letters: [Character] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    letters = clients.map { (name) -> Character in
        return name.lName[name.lName.startIndex]
    }

    letters = letters.reduce([], { (list, name) -> [Character] in
        if !list.contains(name) {
            return list + [name]
        }
        return list
    })

    for c in clients {
        if contacts[c.lName[c.lName.startIndex]] == nil {
            contacts[c.lName[c.lName.startIndex]] = [Client]()
        }

        contacts[c.lName[c.lName.startIndex]]!.append(c)
    }

    for (letter, list) in contacts {
        contacts[letter] = list.sorted(by: { (client1, client2) -> Bool in
            client1.lName < client2.lName
        })
    }
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Name", for: indexPath) as! ClientTableViewCell

    cell.clientName?.text = contacts[letters[indexPath.row]]?[indexPath.row].lName

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You want a section for each letter of the alphabet, followed by a cell for each contact in that section?

Comment: What does your code look like when you set the number of sections and number of rows?

Comment: You don't seem to be using sections at all. You need to have one section per letter and use that to find the right contact in `cellForRow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one section per letter, by implementing numberOfSections method to return this:

```
    return letters.count
```

Change code in cellForRowAt from this:

```
  cell.clientName?.text = contacts[letters[indexPath.row]]?[indexPath.row].lName
```

To this:

```
   cell.clientName?.text = contacts[letters[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row].lName
```